# formatting date in mysql date format using date function

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to pass date to mysql query using php, but i am not getting what i want

my php statement is like that

```
$date_s="01/03/2012";
$date_s=date("YYYY-MM-DD", $date_s);
echo $date_s;
```

its printing `1970197019701970-JanJan-ThuThu`

what i want is to format above date from `01/03/2012` to `2012-03-01`

i know its little thing to format the date but i am not figuring out what to do, i have tried all possible functions and formatting?

Comment: Definitely relevant: http://php.net/date

Comment: 01/03/2012 is 1st march or 3rd january ?

Comment: @air : KingFisher is right it will not work with safarow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$date_s="01/03/2012";
$date_s=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_s));
echo $date_s;
```

Comment: @KingFisher you are right, didnt mentioned that. Asking OP for clearify

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$date = new DateTime($date_s);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

but if you are passing it to MySQL i would recommend

```
 echo $date->format('c');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = '...';
$sqlDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in PHP:

```
$date_s = join('-', array_reverse( explode( '/', $date_s) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

better just use `str_replace` and `date()` functions. it will work.

```
$date_s="01/03/2012";
$date_s =str_replace("/","-",$date_s);
echo $date_s=date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date_s));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <?php
     // this will be helpful for u
    $oldDate="22-3-1986"; //any format date
$newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($oldDate));
    ?>
```